# How to identify the source of the data when reading all of the files in one directory?

Tags: r, dataframe

in one directory, there are bund of files:

```
cpu_server01.csv
cpu_server02.csv
cpu_server03.csv
```

etc

I can read the contents of the file and append it to a dflist as below. But I need to create another column in the dflist and put the name of the file in there?

```
path("C:/Server/web/")
#cpu

filenames <- list.files(path, pattern="cpu_*", full.names=TRUE)

dflist <- lapply(filenames, function(i) {
  read.csv(i, header=T)

})
```

How would I put the name of the file to each ?

```
Date Cpu filename
```

Comment: @Gregor, dflist needs to be a data frame after all.

Comment: `dflist` is not a data frame as you have it, it's a list of data frames. If you want to combine them into a single data frame use `data.table::rbindlist` or `dplyr::bind_rows`. If you use `bind_rows` you can give an argument `.id = filenames` which will automatically add an `".id"` column with the appropriate file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
for(i in 1:length(dflist))
  dflist[[i]]$file_name = filenames[i]
```

Example:

```
filenames=c("a","b")
dflist = list(head(mtcars,3),head(mtcars,3))

for(i in 1:length(dflist))
   dflist[[i]]$file_name = filenames[i]
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb file_name
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4         a
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4         a
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1         a

[[2]]
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb file_name
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4         b
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4         b
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1         b
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Florian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511758/3817004) here are two alternative approaches to deal with this common situation.

#### Name the list elements

Copying the filename as a column of the individual data.frames makes only sense IMHO if you are planning to `rbind()` them into one large data object ( see example below)

If you want to keep *each data.frame separately in the list*, you can *name the list elements* appropriately, e.g.,

```
path <- "."
# get vector of filenames, note that pattern includes the cvs extension
filenames <- list.files(path, pattern = "cpu_.*csv$", full.names = TRUE)
# read files as a list of data.frames
dflist <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE)
# rename list element using file names without path
names(dflist) <- basename(filenames)
```

Note that it's not necessary to define an anonymous function in the call to `lapply()` because `lapply()` passes unrecognized parameters to the called function. So, we can write concisely

```
lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE)
```

instead of

```
lapply(filenames, function(i) read.csv(i, header = TRUE))
```

Now, `dflist` has been named appropriately

> ```
> $cpu_server01.csv
>   V1   V2
> 1  A 1001
> 2  B 1002
> 3  C 1003
>
> $cpu_server02.csv
>   V1   V2
> 1  A 2001
> 2  B 2002
> 3  C 2003
>
> $cpu_server03.csv
>   V1   V2
> 1  A 3001
> 2  B 3002
> 3  C 3003
> ```

#### Identify source file in a combined data object

If the goal is to combine all data chunks in one large data object, the originating source file of each row needs to be identified.

This can be achieved by  [Florian's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511758/3817004) and subsequent rbinding. Or, we can use `data.table`'s `rbindlist()` function.

If the list elements already have been named as described above, we can simply add:

```
combi <- data.table::rbindlist(dflist, idcol = "file.name")
combi
```

> ```
>           file.name V1   V2
> 1: cpu_server01.csv  A 1001
> 2: cpu_server01.csv  B 1002
> 3: cpu_server01.csv  C 1003
> 4: cpu_server02.csv  A 2001
> 5: cpu_server02.csv  B 2002
> 6: cpu_server02.csv  C 2003
> 7: cpu_server03.csv  A 3001
> 8: cpu_server03.csv  B 3002
> 9: cpu_server03.csv  C 3003
> ```

`rbindlist()` has created the id column "file.name" and had populated it with the names of the list elements.

---

Alternatively, we can call `rbindlist()` first and add the file names as factors:

```
library(data.table)
path <- "."
# get vector of filenames, note that pattern includes the cvs extension
filenames <- list.files(path, pattern = "cpu_.*csv$", full.names = TRUE)
# read files as a list of data.frames and combine immediately
combi <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE), idcol = "file.name")
# change file number to appropriately labeled factor
combi[, file.name := factor(file.name, labels = basename(filenames))][]
```

> ```
>           file.name V1   V2
> 1: cpu_server01.csv  A 1001
> 2: cpu_server01.csv  B 1002
> 3: cpu_server01.csv  C 1003
> 4: cpu_server02.csv  A 2001
> 5: cpu_server02.csv  B 2002
> 6: cpu_server02.csv  C 2003
> 7: cpu_server03.csv  A 3001
> 8: cpu_server03.csv  B 3002
> 9: cpu_server03.csv  C 3003
> ```

#### Data

For the sake of reproducibility, the dummy files are created by

```
idx_vec <- 1:3
invisible(sapply(1:3, function(i) {
  x <- data.frame(V1 = LETTERS[idx_vec], V2 = 1000L * i + idx_vec)
  write.csv(x, sprintf("cpu_server%02i.csv", i), row.names = FALSE)
}))
```